# How to reference a static variable in a HTMLDOC content in PHP

Tags: php, class, htmldoc

How can I use a

```
templateize::$subject
```

in a

```
$html = <<<HTMLDOC
abc+abc+ab templateize::$subject

HTMLDOC;
```

in a HTMLDOC content?

Comment: +1 for the question. I learned something new today ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs are here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

<del>The code looks like this:</del>

`<del>`

```
$html = <<<HTMLDOC
abc+abc+ab {${templateize::$subject}}

HTMLDOC;
```

`</del>`

Actually, that's not quite true. If `templateize::$subject == "foo"`, the above will be interpreted as `{$foo}`.

I can't seem to find a possibility to achieve, what you want, except from this:

```
$foo = templateize::$subject;

$html = <<<HTMLDOC
abc+abc+ab $foo

HTMLDOC;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$html = <<<HTMLDOC
abc+abc+ab {$templateize::$subject}

HTMLDOC;
```

OR

```
$html = <<<HTMLDOC
abc+abc+ab $templateize::$subject

HTMLDOC;
```

Comment: And what is the `$templateize` variable holding?